# Сложить цифры в списке

Tags: python

Каким образом можно сложить списки ниже, по принципу `[2, 0.16]+[2, 0.31]+[2, -0.16]+[2, 0.29] = [2, 0.6]` (оставить первое значение и сложить все вторые значения)?
Итог который должен получиться примерно такой `l = [[2, 12.7452], [7, 4.8432], [-9, 42.2], [-14, 9.5242], [17, -5.323], [-18, -11.6573], ...]` (вторые значения суммированы, а первые идут в порядке возрастания, без учета минуса перед цифрой)

```
l = [2, 0.16796830136672278], [7, 0.02264685067233594], [-9, -1.7999825667547869], [-14, 0.35134392666598474], [17, -0.06198644947382464], [-18, -0.26257380354836923], [21, -0.27785051351430345], [28, 0.23018502771016694], [31, 1.2600080640516098], [-6, 0.13243317163050966], [7, -0.7386231715811474], [-11, 0.9637237133569254], [13, -0.347137898030021], [-14, -0.2017398271619146], [15, 0.604400259835622], [-18, -0.3900453639716941], [19, 0.6060690890767692], [21, -0.6480431083380713], [28, 0.5959078218110626], [2, -0.06984020560956135], [-9, -0.16511430990686485], [-11, -0.06845105051407072], [17, 0.2587769674660778], [-18, -0.1457204916004434], [19, -0.39829655866260766], [24, 0.870501048960589], [31, 1.3188360662396783], [2, 0.31743905705865894], [-6, 0.2606195760230025], [7, 0.03598608538032098], [-9, -0.3484600745168345], [13, -0.1622867429459814], [-14, -0.37338018888645613], [17, 1.0035998690956751], [21, 0.5111933721135139], [28, 0.19697700594951703], [30, 0.8566563796956548], [-6, 0.4978363786811951], [7, -0.4372487173586489], [-11, -0.6578679099101669], [13, -0.09856532690833798], [-14, -0.4048694124590007], [15, 0.5023543583004879], [-18, -0.6191993159847172], [19, 0.3916610551486204], [21, -0.699765820943084], [28, 1.0313085582197], [2, -0.16476534900930645], [-9, 0.14147045228523678], [-11, 0.36624425567470437], [17, -0.17408123791103175], [-18, 0.37165544386082916], [19, 0.45534967288887523], [24, 0.5038299266784088], [31, 1.2100016079755664], [2, 0.29197080291971905], [-6, -0.5568186459368464], [7, -0.6239091896051888], [-9, 0.11767925561028807], [13, 0.07676175071621096], [-14, -0.36602818141788496], [19, -1.1413679692290577], [21, 0.12119876597621208], [23, -0.4750131948109652]
```

Comment: Я минусы не ставил, но вы даже не попытались решить задачу, это тут не приветствуется. Подумайте, попробуйте как-то решить, прежде чем просить помощи. А почему вы словарями не пользуетесь? Без них можно обойтись при желании, но решение будет медленное и не оптимальное.

Comment: Простое и относительно короткое решение будет видимо через `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 1):

1. Составляем словарь такого плана:
   `первое число: [числа из списка, у которых первое число как ключ]`
2. Считаем суммы и загоняем в список